# Capistrano mkdir: cannot create directory

Tags: deployment, capistrano, mediatemple

I'm trying to use Capistrano (for the first time) to deploy a website. My web hosting is with MediaTemple. Where the dir structure for a website looks like this:

```
domains/site.com/html/index.html
```

It looks like Capistrano's default deployment tries to create a `var/www` directory to place your application inside.

I'm getting this error when trying to run `cap production deploy`:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory `/var/www': Permission denied
```

I assume I don't have the privileges to create these folders, is there a way around this instead of manually creating them?

Also, would the `var/www` structure be recommended, or would it be worth dumping my application in `domains/site.com`?

This is my first experience with Capistrano, so any help with this is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In a default Capistrano deployment setup, there is a commented line that looks like:

```
# Default deploy_to directory is /var/www/my_app
# set :deploy_to, '/var/www/my_app'
```

You will want to uncomment the `set` line and change the path to be the location you want your application deployed to.